# quota command not found in cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin

I am trying to study linux by using cygwin. I use the command below to export the environment variables.

```
ly@ly-PC /cygdrive/c/Users/yipin/Desktop $  export 
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

I could use other commands such as cd, mv and rm. However, when I use the "quota" command, the response is:

> bash: quota: command not found

There is a quota library in my computer. The directory is:

```
C:\Users\ly\Downloads\http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f\
x86\release\e2fsprogs\libquota-devel
```

Comment: Did you install the `quota` package?

Comment: I do not know how to install the quota package and how to check it has been installed. Could you tell me how? Thank you!

Comment: You will need to compile Cygwin with the quota package selected. Check the Cygwin website.

Comment: I am a beginner in the field. Could you give me a detailed link? Thank you!